# Why isn't my AngularJS post receiving data from the server?

Tags: angularjs

I am posting to the server using the following in AngularJS:

```
$http.post('/myurl', {my: "data"}, function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("returned");
});
```

In Chrome Developer Tools, the server is sending back a 200 OK status message. However, my callback is never triggered (i.e. nothing printing to the console). Why is AngularJS not printing the message even though the server returns OK?

Comment: Read the documentation. `$http.post` returning promise with `then` method. See @Phill answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not seen request written like that, generally you want to do something like:

```
$http.post('/myurl', {my: "data"})
     .success(function(data) {
        console.log("returned");
     });
```

or

```
$http.post('/myurl', {my: "data"})
     .then(function(data) {
        console.log("returned");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 return $http({url: '/myurl' , method: "POST",data:my});
```

you can also  click on F12 chrome console to see the exact error

in order to serr the results data you can add

```
$http({url: '/myurl' , method: "POST",data:my}).then(
function(result){
   console.log(result);
}
```